# Extract common class with different XML namespaces

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, soap, xml-namespaces

I have two identical classes:

```
namespace Models.CSharpNamespace1
{
    [XmlType(Namespace = "http://XmlNamespace1")]
    public partial class TheClass
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string Prop1 { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute]
        public string Prop2 { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute]
        public int Prop3 { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace Models.CSharpNamespace2
{
    [XmlType(Namespace = "http://XmlNamespace2")]
    public partial class TheClass
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string Prop1 { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute]
        public string Prop2 { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute]
        public int Prop3 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I would like to extract `TheClass` to `Models.Common` namespace to share it between `Models.CSharpNamespace1` and `Models.CSharpNamespace2`, but there is a difference between them in namespace in `XmlType` attribute.
This namespace is essential for SOAP, so I can't change it.

What to do?

Comment: What is the problem? can you show what you have tried so far? What prevents you from converting from one class to another after deserialization?

Comment: What have I tried? I have absolutely no idea what to try.

Comment: Why we should know ?  I can't see any problem and the most people too, you have to explain the details, what makes it so special

Comment: So I conclude that I have to find the point where I can get control over serialization of SOAP. May be somewhere in the middleware of ASP.NET core.

Comment: Why you should get a control? why you can not use a common way? This is what would be nice to hear from you.

Comment: What is a common way? I found examples how to use SOAP in ASP.NET Core and they are cryptic to me. Some magic is happening inside.

Comment: I understand. I am amazed how the most banks still use 50 years old technologies. In  this case  I would use a good old asp.net   3. 5 or older since it is working properly with the old staff. Just add an api layer to send the parameters and return data.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it

**POCO class** (XmlTypeAttribute is removed)

```
public partial class TheClass
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public int Prop3 { get; set; }
}
```

**Serialization**

```
public static void SerializeXml()
{
    TheClass obj = new TheClass()
    {
        Prop1 = "Prop1",
        Prop2 = "Prop2",
        Prop3 = 3
    };
    
    //--> Pass the Namespace programmatically here
    XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TheClass), "http://XmlNamespace2");
    
    XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
    namespaces.Add(string.Empty, string.Empty); 
    XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings
    {
        Indent = true,
        OmitXmlDeclaration = true
    };
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    TextWriter w = new StringWriter(sb);
    using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(w, settings))
    {
        s.Serialize(writer, obj, namespaces);
    }       
    
    Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
}
```

Output:

```
<TheClass Prop1="Prop1" Prop2="Prop2" Prop3="3" xmlns="http://XmlNamespace2" />
```

**Sample fiddle**: https://dotnetfiddle.net/2ctFdk